# Icecast/shoutcast streaming on Android

Tags: android, shoutcast

Is there a way to stream shoutcast/icecast on the android? Passing the icecast URL to the mediaplayer does not work and after researching the topic it seems it is because android can't play raw aac files without a media container.

What can I do to get around this?

Thanks

Comment: I know its kinda late, but as this question has no anwer. Can you provide a link for the stream?