# Live stream audio

Tags: android, audio-streaming, http-live-streaming, live-streaming

I need to stream audio to my app as it is being recorded live. How do I do this for Android? I have searched a few sources and didn't get a straight answer on how to do this.

The official documentation says Android supports live streaming over http/https in Android 3.0+. I need to be able to stream to devices with 2.3+. Any suggestion would help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to implement an icecast/shoutcast server. You can find some tips about how to do the Android side on this question: [Icecast/shoutcast streaming on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2568665/icecast-shoutcast-streaming-on-android)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will have to do more research on it.